# regex ansible lineinfile subsection

Tags: regex, ansible

I am fairly new to ansible and have been solving the following problem with a shell script, but the proper way I believe is to use the `lineinfile` module, just not sure how to accomplish this.

Let's say I have a file with the following text in it.

```
<cpu>
   <alarm>
      active = yes
   </alarm>
</cpu>
<disk>
   <alarm>
      active = yes
      <fixed>
         <#>  
            active = yes
            description = File system /
            <inode_error>
               active = yes
               threshold = 2
               message = InodeError
            </inode_error>
         </#>
         <#boot>
            active = yes
            description = File system /boot
            percent = yes
            <error>
               active = yes
               threshold = 5
               message = DiskError
            </error>
         </#boot>
      </fixed>
   </alarm>
</disk>
```

I want to make sure the following section is set correctly.

```
<disk><alarm><fixed><#boot><error>"threshold = 2"</error></#boot></fixed></alarm></disk>
```

is there a way to only (modify/make sure exists) that line, normally this file is much larger with many more sections, but I erased some so the question is readable.

Update:  Modifying this as it is not valid XML and the XML module will not parse the file correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineinfile` scans file per line, so you can't define complex multiline regexp for context definition.

`replace` module support multiline regexp.

If you have `threshold = X` in the file and want to be sure it is set to specific value, you can use this regexp:

```
- replace:
    path: ./test.txt
    regexp: '(<disk>[\s\S]*<alarm>[\s\S]*<#boot>[\s\S]*<error>[\s\S]*)(threshold\s*=\s*\d+)([\s\S]*?<\/error>)'
    replace: '\1threshold = 2\3'
```

It searches for line `threshold\s*=\s*\d+` inside `<disk>...<alarm>...<#boot>...<error>...`.
This code is idempotent – so if `threshold = 2`, then nothing is done.

But if there is no `threshold = X` string, it will fail. You should construct more complex regular expression for that case.

Comment: This got me on the right track.  The following regex ended up working as I have more sections following.   (<disk>[\s\S]*<alarm>[\s\S]*<#boot>[\s\S]*<error>[\s\S]*)(threshold\s*=\s*\d+)([\s\S]*<\/error>[\s\S]*?<\/#boot>) ...  The only downside is the replace module with this regex is terribly slow.  Much slower than the shell script.  So for now I will note this solution and keep in place my script as i cant wait 30+seconds for a single localhost regex replace.

Comment: nice ..... but: it only edits the last occurrence of the pattern. What if there are more disks? or: how to get the regex less greedy?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the lineinfile module (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html) where you could write a regex to modify/add the line and use the validate function to run a command to ensure that the xml file has the proper syntax.

If you are on Ansible 2.4 you can use the xml module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/xml_module.html) and use the attribute parameter to check if the xpath in xml file is set, like that:

```
- name: Read attribute value
  xml:
    path: /foo/bar.xml
    xpath: /business/website/validxhtml
    content: attribute
    attribute: validatedon
  register: xmlresp
```

regards